# Compile error with decltype of iterator de-reference

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, decltype, c++17

What am I missing here? Why can't I use decltype to define the value_type of an iterator? The code below gets inscrutable compile-time errors when I use decltype rather than iterator_traits, but only if I also use value_type to declare a vector.

Visual Studio 2017,  C++17 rev. 15.6 Preview

```
#include <vector>
template<class Ptr >
void foo(Ptr beg) {
    *beg = 1;  // Cool, babies.
//  using value_type = decltype(*beg); // COMPILER ERROR when buf declared below
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Ptr>::value_type;
    std::vector<value_type> buf(1); // Remove this and decltype compiles.
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> bar(1);
    foo(std::begin(bar));
    *(std::begin(bar)) = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

By request...

```
error C2528: 'const_pointer': pointer to reference is illegal
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the full compiler error in the question.

Comment: @chris -  
I doubt it, but okay.

Comment: Someone mercifully deleted all except the first line of errors.

Comment: `decltype(*beg)` gives `int&`, not `int`.

Comment: @O'Neil - Ah ha. Now what to do? I would prefer to avoid iterator_traits...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for the same reason when you have:

```
void foo(int *beg)
```

then

```
decltype(*beg)
```

Does not give you an `int`. You get an `int &` here. That's what, essentially, your `using` declaration ends up getting: a reference, an uninvited hitch-hiker.

If you insist on using `decltype`, you can do:

```
using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*beg)>::type;
```

In order to ditch the unwelcome hitch-hiker.

Comment: I'll note that if a `const_iterator` is given instead, this will still fail because of having a vector of `const` things. In that case, the upcoming `std::remove_cv_t` trait is more appropriate, which is equivalent to `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`, or you can use `std::decay_t`, which is probably more appropriate for obtaining a type that will be stored in a vector anyway.

Comment: It's not const. The actual code is a thread-parallel stable_sort.

Comment: Excellent!  Iterator_traits not required.  And I am not the least bit embarrassed for asking a dumb question.